# Jenkins build for android sdk problem Failed to install the following SDK components:

Tags: android, jenkins, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

I try to build android app via jenkins app but have a problem with android sdk.
I installed version of android sdk on linux server and config variables and do it jenkins site.

Build message:

```
Started by user XYZ
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace//.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url gitlabgit # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from gitlabgit
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.17.1'
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- gitlab.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 226418a2e4d787c8d75dd497088efa4347cf7bd0 (refs/remotes/origin/develop)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 226418a2e4d787c8d75dd497088efa4347cf7bd0 # timeout=10
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git branch -D develop # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b develop 226418a2e4d787c8d75dd497088efa4347cf7bd0 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Merge branch 'jciszewski/FixCardResponse' into 'develop'"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 226418a2e4d787c8d75dd497088efa4347cf7bd0 # timeout=10
[] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins686224158862483808.sh
+ chmod +x gradlew
+ ./gradlew clean
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:clean UP-TO-DATE

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
2 actionable tasks: 2 up-to-date
+ ./gradlew assembleDebug
File /var/lib/jenkins/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in /home/face/android-sdk/android-sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)".
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 30 in /home/face/android-sdk/android-sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 30 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 30 (revision: 3)".
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
      platforms;android-30 Android SDK Platform 30
      build-tools;30.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3
  The SDK directory is not writable (/home/face/android-sdk/android-sdk)


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
[PostBuildScript] - [INFO] Executing post build scripts.
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have a problem with resolve it (i tried changed permissions to 777 but still not working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the ownership of android SDK

`chown -R <user_name> <directory_name>`

Comment: I changed it this way to 777 but I tried this in /opt/sdk folder and in some reason it wouldn't like work correctly in this directory after i moved it to other and changed it once again it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Resolve by change directory of sdk from /opt/sdk to /home/user/sdk